# Swift Error - Type of expression is ambiguous without more context

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift5

I've been stuck on this problem for a while now and similar questions of this topic didn't help me solve this issue.

```
public extension NSString {
    func textRectWithFont(font: UIFont, width: CGFloat) -> CGRect {
        let contraint: CGSize = CGSize(width: width, height: 500000);
        var rect: CGRect

        var attributes: [NSAttributedString.Key: Any] = [
            .font: font
        ]

        rect = self.boundingRect(with: contraint,
                options: [.usesLineFragmentOrigin, .usesFontLeading],
                attributes: attributes,
                context: nil)

        return rect;
    }
}
```

When I then use that method on this line

```
let textHeight = NSString(textLabel?.text).textRectWithFont(font: textLabel?.font, width: textFrame?.size.width).size.height
```

it gives me the error "Type of expression is ambiguous without more context"

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Because textLabel and textFrame are optional so you use optional parameters and the compiler can't match the call against your function that takes non-optional parameters. First try to unwrap the values using `if let` or allow optional arguments to the function and add error handling inside it.

Comment: That makes sense. Thanks for the explanation!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your giving optional parameters to your function which is indeed ambiguous.
best solution will be to unwrap before passing like this.

```
if let input_textLabel = textLabel?.font, let input_Width = textFrame?.size.width {
let textHeight = NSString(textLabel?.text).textRectWithFont(font: input_textLabel, width: input_Width).size.height
}
```

Or you can also take optional parameter into function and then unwrap it inside and work on it.

```
func textRectWithFont(font: UIFont?, width: CGFloat?) -> CGRect {
if let font  = font , let width = width. { your rest of function}

return value
}
```